# Is there a way to get toad to refresh data at intervals

Tags: toad

From time to time I am monitoring data in TOAD waiting for some process to run.

Is there a way to set a toad query or data tab to refresh at regular intervals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no feature like this in Toad. For a query in the Editor it's easy enough to hit F9 and execute again when you're ready to look at the data.

Answer (score 1):

I found that in new versions(I got 13.2) and wanted to share this, Toad supports automatic grid refresh, but with tricks

You have to open describe object window(simply press **F4** on a table name), then in **Data** tab you can see **Auto Refresh** and enter the interval value! wow! I waited so long for this feature!